# Protractor - Counting the no.of elements and Display all the elements with For loop is Not getting executed

Tags: android, selenium, protractor, appium

I am working on Protractor with Android hybrid app. I am trying to count the elements and Retrieve and display all the elements. I am able to get the count of the elements. But when I try to display,  the For loop is not getting executed, nor gives any Error.

Kindly Advise. Here's my code below.

```
   var n1 = browser.element.all(by.className('program-details-directive-container')).count();
  browser.element.all(by.className('program-details-directive-container')).
  then( function(n1)
   {
    for(var i=0; i<n1; ++i)
    {
      n1(i).getText().then( function(text1)
      {
       console.log(text1);
       })
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the promise chain is not continuing try the following with the help of bluebird

```
  var Promise = require('bluebird');

  var n1 = browser.element.all(by.className('program-details-directive-container')).count();
  browser.element.all(by.className('program-details-directive-container'))
    .then(function(n1) {
      var promises = n1.map(function(elm){
        return elm.getText().then( function(text1) {
          console.log(text1);
        })
      });

      return Promise.all(promises);
    });
  });
```